# Did I create my Java Objects Correctly?

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-structures

**Main Table**

```
ID  COUNTRY_ID  STATE_ID    Status      QTY[%]
1   1       1       Confirmed   80
2   1       1       Tentative   20
3   1       2       Confirmed   70
4   1       2       Tentative   30
5   2       3       Confirmed   50
6   2       3       Tentative   50
```

**Country Table**

```
COUNTRY_ID  COUNTRY_NAME
1       United States
2       India
```

**State Table**

```
STATE_ID    STATE_NAME
1       New York        
2       New Jersey  
3       Delhi
```

I have a user interface where data needs to be represented as tree and user has the ability to update the qty at any level and it should distributed accordingly -

For example, UI would look like -

```
ALL
    Total Confirmed     200         
    Total Tentative     100 

United States
    Total Confirmed     150
    Total Tentative     50  

    New York
        Confirmed       80
        Tentative       20
    New Jersey
        Confirmed       70
        Tentative       30

India
    Total Confirmed     50
    Total Tentative     50  

    Delhi
        Confirmed       50
        Tentative       50
```

If we observe closely, data represented at the lower level is directly from the database but at the upper levels they are just aggregation of data from lower levels.

I guess I have a requirement where user can update the totals at any level they need to be distributed to lower and upper levels accodingly.

I am trying to use pre-order and post-order tree traversals from the below implementation [n-ary tree with k-nodes]

http://vivin.net/2010/01/30/generic-n-ary-tree-in-java/

```
class State {
    private String name ;
    private double confirmed ;
    private double tentative ;
    private boolean isUpdated ;

    // getters and setters
}


class Country {
    private String name ;
    private double totalConfirmed ;
    private double totalTentative ;
    private boolean isUpdated ;

    private List<State> states ;
    // getters and setters

    public void getTotalConfirmed () {
        // iterate through the list of states and add all the confirmed values from every state and return ;
    }
}

class ALL {

    private double totalConfirmed ;
    private double totalTentative ;
    private boolean isUpdated ;
    private List<countries> countries;
    // getters and setters

    public void getTotalConfirmed() {
        // iterate through the list of all countries and add all the confirmed values from every country and return ;
    }

    // similary setTotalConfirmed as well
}
```

Question -

1. Is my java structure correct and solves my purpose?
2. If there are updates at both lower and upper level, Lower level values take precedence and are never updated, so I am maintaining a boolean isUpdated variable to see if we need to honor the updates at lower level?
3. Is pre-order, post-order structure really useful to me for traversing the tree up and down across all nodes ? Because, if I update something at ALL level, it needs to be distributed across all lower levels and vice-a-versa.

This is a simple representation but I am dealing with a much complex structure where I have at least 5 - 6 levels of data.

Comment: If the user changes a quantity at a leaf, presumably, the resulting updates are to revise the totals on all ancestor nodes. But if you change the qty at a non-leaf node, how do you want to update the descendants? Increase by percentage? And what happens to rounding, if you were in fact increasing by percentage?

Comment: it's a good start but you should look to see how you can abstract it a bit more. It looks to me you only need one class type being Node.

Comment: @BevynQ, a simple `Node` construct will most likely suffice, but it really depends on the nitty-gritties of how the qty updates need to happen. If there is a bunch of node type specific business logic, for example, there is more complexity, either in the form of node subtypes or multiple update computation strategy objects...

Comment: If a quantity is changed at the non-leaf node, changes to the descendants are either incremented/decremented by percentage. Rounding  can be to the nearest integer. Also, total percentage can be greater than 100 [just an application requirement]. An example could be an  RSVP. You invited 100 couples, 100 accepted, but 102 couples turned up [last minute guests].

Comment: Also, like I mentioned my application requirement is much more complex on similar lines, where I have several other fields that are calculation based. For example, in all levels I have another field which is actually (confirmed % / tentative %) etc. Not sure, if I made it clear but distribution needs to happen both upward and downwards based on what was updated first.

Comment: @Dilum Ranatunga and BevynQ - If I use tree traversal technique, is  my data, node/parent child relationship data not being duplicated? I mean for a country node, when I insert the node into tree, I am storing what my parent [ALL] and children [states] nodes are. In this case, am I not ending up with duplicate data ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use XML for your tree data structure, I would recommend using Apache XML http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/api.html, where you have easy traverse to your entire tree.

Comment: what advantages does this xml approach give me than the one I mentioned? Also, like I mentioned my structure is much complex and we are planning to do AJAX calls for doing these calculations!

Comment: each node has a name in XML, traversing is much easier via apache api, they have a lot of methods to get the specific node by name, value etc.